# A question about the determinant of a binary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Is it true that for every positive integers $n$ and $m < n$ there exists a square matrix of order $n$ that contains only zeros and ones, whose columns contain exactly $m$ ones  (and hence $n(n-m)$ zeros) and whose determinant is not equal to zero?  It is clear that one can speak of rows instead of columns.  Here is an example of such a determinant for $n=5$ and $m=3$:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
$$

I see experimentally using MathCAD that it seems to be true.  But how to prove it?

Comment: @AndreasLenz what you construct is only true for $m, n$ being a minimal counter example would be to choose $n = 4, m = 2$. You can easily see that you have two pairs of columns summing up to the same value so not linearly dependent.

Comment: Assuming that *binary* = arithmetic done modulo two, then the claim is false. If there is an even number of ones in each row, then the row space is contained in the zero sum subspace, and hence the matrix won't have full rank.

Answer (score 5):

This depends on the ring/field. E.g. every $3\times3$ binary matrix with exactly $2$ ones on each column must either possess repeated columns or be obtained by scrambling the columns of
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1&1\\ 1&0&1\\ 1&1&0}.
$$
Therefore all such matrices are singular in a commutative ring of characteristic $2$.

However, the answer to your question is affirmative in every commutative ring of characteristic $0$. It suffices to prove the assertion over $\mathbb Z$ by mathematical induction. The base case $(n,m)=(2,1)$ is solved by picking $A=I$. In the inductive step, suppose $n\ge3$. If $m=1$, simply pick $A=I$. If $m>1$, then $n-1>m-1\ge1$ and by induction assumption, there exists some nonsingular $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ binary matrix $B$ with exactly $m-1$ ones on each column. Let
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&\mathbf1^T\\ \mathbf u&B}
$$
where $\mathbf 1\in\mathbb Z^{n-1}$ denotes the vector of ones and $\mathbf u$ is any binary integer vector containing exactly $m$ ones and $n-m-1$ zeroes. Since $\mathbf1^TB=(m-1)\mathbf1^T$,
$$
\det(A)=
\det\left[\pmatrix{1&-\frac{1}{m-1}\mathbf1^T\\ \mathbf0&I}\pmatrix{0&\mathbf1^T\\ \mathbf u&B}\right]
=\det\pmatrix{-\frac{\mathbf1^T\mathbf u}{m-1}&\mathbf0^T\\ \mathbf u&B}
=\frac{-m}{m-1}\det(B)\ne0.
$$
The previous line also shows that if $B$ is an integer (but not necessarily binary) matrix whose column sums are all equal to some $k\ne0$, then $k$ must divide $\det(B)$.

Answer (score 2):

It's True!. Consider the following matrix:

In the column the first $m$ entries are one. In the next $m$ columns the $i + 1$' th column will be the same as first column with $i$'th and last entries swapped. In the next $n - m - 1$ columns the $m + 1 + i$'th column will consist of the first column except that the first and $m + i$'th components are swapped.

To show the matrix is nonsingular we will prove that it's rows are independent. Assume that $a_1, \dots, a_n$ are the coefficients of the linear combinations of rows adding up to zero. Then the first component being zero implies:

$a_1 + \dots + a_m = 0$ $(*)$

the $i + 1$'th component begin zero for $1 <= i <= m$ means will result to the equation:

$a_1 + \dots + a_{i - 1} + a_{i} + \dots a_{m} + a_{n} = 0$

comparing this with $(*)$ implies:

$a_1 = a_2 = \dots = a_m = a_n$

Now the equation corresponding to the $m + 1 + i$'th equation being equal to zero for $1 <= i <= n - m - 1$ implies that:

$a_2 + \dots + a_m + a_{m + i} = 0$

again comparing this with $(*)$ results in :

$a_1 = a_2 = \dots = a_n$

pluging into $(*)$ will result:

$a_1 = a_2 = \dots a_n = 0$

so the matrix is nonsingular so the determinant is nonzero.

Here is an example for $n = 6$ and $m = 3$:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can do even better, if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. In such a case we can make a matrix with nonzero determinant where each column has $m$ ones *and* each row has $m$ ones also.

With $m$ and $n$ relatively prime, start by placing any desired permutation of ones and zeroes in the first row. Then for the second row, advance each 0 or 1 entry one place to the right, wrapping the bit in the last column around to the first column. Thus with $n=5, m=3$ the first two rows might read

1 1 1 0 0

0 1 1 1 0

Iterate this cyclic permutation process for the remaining rows, so the complete matrix in this example would read

1 1 1 0 0

0 1 1 1 0

0 0 1 1 1

1 0 0 1 1

1 1 0 0 1

with determinant $3$.